# Why is there a memory limit but not a storage limits for computers

Tags: memory, storage

If a computer has a 32 bit copy of windows is only able to use a max of 4GB of RAM. But why is the same computer able to use 500+GB of storage? If there is a limit to the RAM, shouldn't the same limit exist for storage?

Comment: Short answer no: Storage is limited by the file system and device driver design.

Comment: There are storage limits as well, they’re just file system-dependent and much higher than RAM limits. For example, NTFS in Windows XP has a maximum volume size of 256TB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have been ***several*** storage size limits that have been imposed and worked around over the years.

From the [History of BIOS and IDE limits](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Large-Disk-HOWTO-4.html) the various limits that we have seen are:

> - ATA Specification (for IDE disks) - the 137 GB limit
> - BIOS Int 13 - the 8.5 GB limit
> - The 528 MB limit
> - The 2.1 GB limit (April 1996)
> - The 3.2 GB limit
> - The 4.2 GB limit (Feb 1997)
> - The 7.9 GB limit
> - The 8.4 GB limit
> - The 33.8 GB limit (August 1999)
> - The 137 GB limit (Sept 2001)
> - The 2 TiB limit

Read the linked article for the details of each limit.  Generally though they are different from memory limits due to the 512-byte sector and 4096 (default) cluster sizes, combined with other factors.

We have already passed the "2TB Limit" listed and it is specific to MBR disks. GPT partitioned disk do not have this limit.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, no. The CPU doesn't directly work with disk storage the same way it uses RAM – that is, it doesn't have dedicated instructions which would accept HDD sector numbers.

Instead the OS has to send commands to the disk controller in order to retrieve some sectors and copy them to RAM (or vice versa, write some data from RAM to disk sectors). Only once in RAM does the data become accessible to the CPU – and the CPU doesn't care how it arrived there.

(Remember that CPU "bitness" primarily describes those instructions which deal with memory addresses, but *not necessarily* those which deal with plain numbers. So a 32-bit CPU can still work with larger numbers than that. E.g. when it needs to compute a 64-bit sector address. It might take a few more instructions than working with a 32-bit number, but it's still doable.)

That said, there could be storage limitations *elsewhere.* For example, IDE disks originally only had commands which accepted 22-bit sector addresses. To support larger disks, IDE needed new commands to be defined for 28-bit and eventually 48-bit sector addresses. But that's not related to the CPU at all.